# How to add Serde in pallets\kitties\src\cargo.toml

Tags: kitties, build

While doing the tutorial of "Build the Substrate Kitties Chain" there comes a section https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/kitties/pt1/#uniqueness-custom-types-and-storage-maps

In this there it says 'Along with this code, we'll need to import serde. Add this to your pallet's Cargo.toml file, using the matching version as Substrate upstream.'

So How to add serde in  cargo.toml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add serde in cargo.toml you should go in pallets\kitties\src\cargo.toml  and in the [dependencies] section add a line like:

`serde = {version="1.0.136", feature= ["derive"]}`

Just keep in mind that the version keeps on updating. So You may have to update the version. Currently, on the date of writing this answer version is 1.0.136

Comment: dont you have to disable the `std` / default features?

Answer (score 3):

Run `cargo update -p sp-io` to fix any problems with version mismatch with Substrate.

Answer (score 1):

```
[dependencies]
serde = "1.0"
```